# What is dependencies between net core and net standard in nuget packages

Tags: dependencies, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I try to add AutoMapper for test .net core application with 2 target frameworks:

- .net core 1.1
- .net framework 461

Also My app references on ClassLibrary1 project that target net standard 1.6

And I have doubts adding nuget package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.

[image]

1. If I select the newest version of nuget package, I see in its dependencies .Net Standart 2.0, does It mean I'm able to add this package only to project, that targets .net core 2.0 or net standard 2.0?
2. If I select older version 2.0.0 (as on screen above) It will have 3 dependecies platform. Does It mean I'm able to add this package to WebApplication2 (as it references net core 1.1 and net fw 461) and moreover I'm able to add this package to my ClassLibrary?

Answer (score 2):

> If I select the newest version of nuget package, I see in its
>   dependencies .Net Standart 2.0, does It mean I'm able to add this
>   package only to project, that targets .net core 2.0 or net standard
>   2.0?

You are correct. As [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) shows, .NET Standard 2.0 could only be referenced by .NET Core 2.0 and higher, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and higher or .NET Standard 2.0 and higher.

> If I select older version 2.0.0 (as on screen above) It will have 3
>   dependecies platform. Does It mean I'm able to add this package to
>   WebApplication2 (as it references net core 1.1 and net fw 461) and
>   moreover I'm able to add this package to my ClassLibrary?

You can add this package to an application that targets .NET Framework 4.5.1 and higher, or to any .NET Core application since .NET Core supports all versions of .NET Standard. Or you can add the package to a class library that targets .NET Standard 1.1 and higher. Moreover, if your class library targets .NET Standard 1.1-1.5, the package will have just 2 dependencies, otherwise (1.6-2.0) it will have three.